# what is the equivalent of UBound and Split(vb.net) in c#?

Tags: vb.net-to-c#

i have codes like this in vb.net

```
If UBound(aTicketEntry) < 17
```

and

```
aTicketEntry = Split(sBarcodeValidation, "|")
```

and i try to code them like this but i got error on both them

```
aTicketEntry = Split(sBarcodeValidation,"|");
```

and

```
if ((UBound(aTicketEntry) < 17))
```

how can i fix this? or what is the equivalent of *`UBound`* and *`Split`*?

Answer (score 0):

For UBound() you would use [.length](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.length(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1). For example:

```
If (aTicketEntry.length < 16) { /*…*/}
```

Note that I changed the 17 to 16, this is because C#'s length property will index from 0 instead of 1.

For Split() I would just use the [String.Split()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131450(v=vs.110).aspx) method, its similar just a change in syntax:

```
string[] aTicketEntry;
aTicketEntry = sBarcodeValidation.Split("|");
```

Apologies about the late response I didn't realize this tag was so quiet, I'll make a point to check for responses if you're still working on this.